# How can I delete last inserted data without losing complete data

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I have bulk inserted the data to SQL table using Flat File. I just want to delete the data which was inserted at the end without loosing the complete data. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have any Identity Column(autoIncrement) or datetime in Flat File?

Comment: If the target table already has some data and you want to delete the last inserted row just from the new data inserted ..`OUTPUT` clause can be used with `Insert` statement to get the list of whole new set of data being inserted `INTO` a temp table..that you can use to get the `Target` row to delete..

Comment: Post some info about the target table to help you further..

Comment: If the inserted data had a primary key, you could always use it to write a delete statement for the rows you don't want.  You could also alter the flat file by removing the problem row in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the identity column to know the last records. For example,  `ORDER BY ID DESC` to get the last records and then delete them:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID IN(
    SELECT  
    TOP 1
    ID
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    ORDER BY id DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a autoincrement identity, you can use the @@IDENTITY system variable.

It tells you the last inserted value for the identity column.

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE IdColumn = @@IDENTITY
```

[@@IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql)